# Mapping array elements using a function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

New to Kotlin from Python. In Python, I can simply use the code below to pass each element of a List to a multiline function and return an iterator of the result.

```
countArr = list(map(countReps, arr))
```

In Kotlin, I found that I had to do the following. Am I missing something?

````
fun LetterCountI(str: String): String {
  val arr = str.split(" ")
  var transform:(String) -> Int = {countReps(it)}
  val countArr = arr.map(transform)
  val mxIndex:Int 
  var ans:String
  if (countArr.max()!=1){
    mxIndex = countArr.indexOf(countArr.max())
    ans = arr[mxIndex]
  } else {
    ans = "-1"
  } 
  return ans;
  
}
fun countReps(str: String): Int {
  var m = mutableMapOf<Char, Int>()
  var v:Int
  for (c in str){
    if (c in m.keys){
      v = m[c]?:0
      m.put(c,v+1)
    } else {
      m.put(c,1)
    }
  }
  return m.values.max() ?: 0
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding your code, but one thing I can tell you is that you can replace

```
var transform:(String) -> Int = {countReps(it)}
val countArr = arr.map(transform)
```

with

```
val countArr = arr.map(::countReps)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the line you ask about, just about all of that code could be rewritten more concisely and idiomatically in Kotlin. For example:

```
fun String.wordWithMostRepeatedLetters()
    = split(" ")
    .associateWith{ it.maxRepeatedLetters() }
    .filter{ it.value > 1 }
    .maxByOrNull{ it.value }?.key ?: "-1"

fun String.maxRepeatedLetters()
    = groupBy{ it }.map{ it.value.size }.maxOrNull() ?: 0
```

I've renamed the functions to try to explain what they give; replaced the `countArr` list with a map from each word to its count, so that you don't need to re-scan it to find the word resulting; and changed both functions to take a String receiver instead of a parameter. Then, because each variable was only used once, I removed them and made it all in-line, using an expression body for each function.

Some of those things don't always improve clarity, of course, especially for long functions — but I hope it demonstrates how concise Kotlin can be. (Hopefully without sacrificing maintainability. Which version would be easier to read? Which would be more likely to harbour subtle bugs?)

It's still not clear what the hard-coded "-1" return value indicates, though… If no word has any repeated letters, a null return would be more idiomatic. (Or it would be simpler just to return the first word, removing the `filter()` call, and returning null only if the string is blank.)

Comment: Thanks. This is rather mind-blowing for me and I will need to study it in detail.